# Calling Typescript function from html2canvas in angular 2

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas in angular 2 to capture the webpage but i need to send the string image to the server side using a webapi post call

```
imageDownload() {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

I am unable to access this typescript function from html2canvas,how can i access this method to send the image string to the server side

```
AddImagesResource(image: any) {
    this.imagesService.addCanvasResource(image)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('Success', 'Changes Saved Succesfully');
        },
        error => {
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('Error', 'Error Occured');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add in Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"html2canvas": "0.5.0-beta4",
"@types/html2canvas": "0.5.32"
.......
}
```

run npm install.

you might encounter the error related html2canvas not found or undefined.
to solve this with systemjs:

```
   map: {

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  ...............

  // other libraries
  'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  'html2canvas': 'npm:html2canvas' //for html canvas
 }
packages: {
  .................
   rxjs: {
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   },
   html2canvas: {
     main:'./dist/html2canvas.js',
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
 }
```

now you will have the complete reference of html2canvas.

i have created the imagedata as dataURI and Blob object of the image.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container" #container>    
   <img id="imgtag" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTexytN9PLhK7bFL-OofVQ9EYmXNhrZP9plY-_L6lKoycVmcjVw"
    alt="Smiley face" height="420" width="420">
   <div style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)=snapShot()>Snap Shot</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
 import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
 import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
 export class AppComponent {
 @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
 snapShot() {
     let dataURI = this.createThumbnail(this.container.nativeElement);
 }

createThumbnail(blockelement: any) {
let element = blockelement.querySelector('#imgtag');
console.log(element, 'element')
if (element !== null && element !== undefined) {
  html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas: any) {
    let dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log('img', dataURI);

    let blobObject = this.dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
    console.log('img', blobObject);
    //this.AddImagesResource(blobObject) your case
    //AddImagesResource will call the service method which can
    //post this blob object as multipart file
    //this formdata and httppost call should in service layer,in your case its imagesService.
    /*
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', blobObject);
      console.log(formData, 'formData');
      return this.http.post(API_URL.saveThumbnailURL, formData).map((res: Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
    })        */
     }.bind(this));
   }
 }
  dataURItoBlob(dataURI: string) {
  let byteString: any;
  if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  else
    byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  let mimeString: any = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

  // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  let blob: any = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    blob[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([blob], {
    type: mimeString
  });
}
}
```

you can send this stringdata/blob Object to server as multipart file using formdata.

Hope this will help

Comment: i am getting  error Cannot read property 'http' of null in the console

Comment: After blob object is created, u need to call ur service method like  this.AddImagesResource(blobObject)

Comment: thats what my issue is , in the html2canvas function i am unable to access the type script method  let blobObject = this.dataURItoBlob(dataURI); it is unable to access the typescript method this.dataURItoBlob(dataURI) or this.AddImagesResource(blobObject)

Comment: html2canvas excuting in different context, use .bind(this).    html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas: any) {
    let dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        let blobObject = this.dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
        //this.AddImagesResource(blobObject) your case    
    
     }.bind(this));

Answer (score 0):

You can use (click) event on an element and assign the function to it,

```
 <button  (click)="AddImagesResource(img)"></button>
```

if you need to call the function inside the ts , you can do this,

```
this.AddImagesResource(imgData);
```

Comment: i need to send imgData  from html2canvas to AddImagesResource(image: any)

Comment: then just use this.AddImagesResource(imgData)

Answer (score 0):

That's what `Zone.js` in an angular app is actually for, and you can use it explicitly to call into an angular app. So, in your component you would do something similar to this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window['addImagesResource'] = (imgData) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.AddImagesResource(imgData);
      });
    };
  }

  /* omitted for brevity */
}
```

And then from html2canvas you can just call `window.addImagesResource(imgData)` as you'd expect, and ngZone should handle putting it in the right context.

**Edit:**
I created a plunker that illustrates how to do it using a button click and plain old javascript code.

https://embed.plnkr.co/erIdbP/

Comment: i am getting an compilation error 'property addImagesResource does not exist on type 'Window' when i added window.addImagesResource(imgData);

Comment: That's because the window contract doesn't have that method exposed. In the example posted, that's why I added it as `window['addImagesResource']` - which has the same net effect.

Comment: ngOnInit() {

        window['addImagesResource'] = (imgData: any) => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    this.AddImagesResource(imgData);
                });
            };
    }           but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Hey, I've added a plunker example that shows what I mean - and shows setting an image from external javascript (a simple html button onclick event). Hopefully that helps?